# angular-ui-router nested views and "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm using the latest version of [IonicFramework](http://ionicframework.com/) which uses angular-ui-router 0.2.8 under the hood. This is my first time using ui-router so I'm probably making a stupid mistake, but I can't figure out what it is. When I navigate to a new state / set of views I've just added, I get a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error and the Chrome tab crashes.

My base HTML is extremely simple:

```
<body ng-app="checkinApp" ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
    <nav-view></nav-view>
</body>
```

And here is the route config for the relevant screens:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('event', {
        url: "/event"
        ,templateUrl: "templates/event.html"
        ,controller: "MainCtrl"
    })
    .state('event.chooseEvent', {
        url: "/choose"
        ,templateUrl: "templates/chooseEvent.html"
        ,controller: "MainCtrl"
    })
    .state('event.eventCheckin', {
        url: "/checkin"
        ,templateUrl: "templates/eventCheckin.html"
        ,controller: "MainCtrl"
    });

     // if none of the above are matched, go to this one
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/choose");
});
```

Simply starting the app with the above route configuration causes the error, no other interaction is necessary.

Here are my views...

**event.html:**

Note the `<nav-view></nav-view>` block, where I'm expecting the child views to render.

```
<side-menus>

    <!-- page content -->
    <pane side-menu-content>
        <header class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleMenu()"></button>
            <h1 class="title">Checkin</h1>
        </header>

        <nav-view></nav-view>

    </pane>

    <side-menu side="left">
        <content>navigation menu content here</content>
    </side-menu>

</side-menus>
```

**eventCheckin.html:**

```
<content has-header="true" on-refresh="refreshAttendees()">

    <!-- for pull to refresh -->
    <refresher></refresher>

    <ul class="list">
        <li
            ng-repeat="person in attendees | orderBy:'firstname' | orderBy:'lastname'"
            item="person"
            class="item item-toggle"
            >
                {{person.lastname}}, {{person.firstname}}
                <label class="toggle">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="person.arrived" ng-click="toggleArrived(person)" />
                    <div class="track">
                        <div class="handle"></div>
                    </div>
                </label>
        </li>
    </ul>

</content>
```

**chooseEvent.html:**

```
<div><br/><br/><br/>Swipe right to choose an Event</div>
```

Aside from the call stack infinite recursion, I'm not getting any other errors in the console. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example helped point-pin a bug within the navView directive. I've since put the fix in the nightly build which will go in our next release.

One thing to point out is that the `eventmenu` state has `abstract: true`, because the side menu itself its not its own view, but instead a container for views.

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#wiki-abstract-states

Below is an example of using an abstract state for a side menu.

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('eventmenu', {
        url: "/event",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "event-menu.html"
      })
      .state('eventmenu.home', {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
          'menuContent' :{
            templateUrl: "home.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
        url: "/check-in",
        views: {
          'menuContent' :{
            templateUrl: "check-in.html",
            controller: "CheckinCtrl"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
        url: "/attendees",
        views: {
          'menuContent' :{
            templateUrl: "attendees.html",
            controller: "AttendeesCtrl"
          }
        }
      })
```

For the markup, the main `<nav-view>` is at the root of the body, and the `<nav-bar>` is within `<pane side-menu-content>`. Note that Ionic uses `<nav-view>` instead of Angular UI Router's `<ui-view>` because Ionic's navView directive comes with a built-in navigation and animation system.

Next, the `event-menu.html` (which is an abstract state), has a child navView directive named `menuContent`, which is where all the other states will plug their views into.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">       
  <nav-view></nav-view>
</div>

<script id="event-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <side-menus>

    <pane side-menu-content>
      <nav-bar type="bar-positive"
               back-button-type="button-icon"
               back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back"></nav-bar>
      <nav-view name="menuContent"></nav-view>
    </pane> 

    <side-menu side="left">
      <header class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
        <div class="title">Left Menu</div>
      </header>
      <content has-header="true">
        <ul class="list">
          <a href="#/event/check-in" class="item">Check-in</a>
          <a href="#/event/attendees" class="item">Attendees</a>
        </ul>
      </content>
    </side-menu>

  </side-menus>
</script>
```

I put together a quick codepen here:
http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/EtbrF

Also, at the time of writing this the codepen uses the nightly build since some of the requirements for your demo are not in a release yet.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I put the side-menu inside of a view because I don't want it available on all views; particularly on the auth view. Is there a way to disable it per-view?

Comment: So does this mean that my problem stems from using side-menus inside a view? Is it a root-only component?